# Angular compilation slow

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-cli

I have an **API** in **Symfony-PHP**, which I test it with **postman** and it works like a charm. But when I do `ng serve --aot --optimization` the application starts to build and the message of `compiled successfully.` takes more than a minute.
When I need to make a change to an `html` component such as a letter, it re-compiles the entire project and takes too long for such a small change.

The `--watch` parameter is set to `true` by default, which is ok. I don't know if anyone knows why this compilation is so slow.

**Versions:**

```
Angular CLI: 6.2.2
Node: 8.12.0
OS: win32 x64
Angular:
...

Package                      Version
------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect    0.8.2
@angular-devkit/core         0.8.2
@angular-devkit/schematics   0.8.2
@schematics/angular          0.8.2
@schematics/update           0.8.2
rxjs                         6.2.2
typescript                   2.9.2


oscar@ubuntu:~$: ng s --aot --optimization


****************************************************************************************
This is a simple server for use in testing or debugging Angular applications locally.
It hasn't been reviewed for security issues.

DON'T USE IT FOR PRODUCTION!
****************************************************************************************
** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **
 10% building modules 7/8 modules 1 active ...s\orquestados-front-user\src\styles.cssBrowserslist: caniuse-lite is outdated. Please run next command `n 70% building modules 646/646 modules 0 activei ｢wdm｣: wait until bundle finished: /pages/offer/management/219702                                             92% chunk asset optimization TerserPlugini ｢wdm｣: wait until bundle finished: /pages/offer/management/219702
i ｢wdm｣: wait until bundle finished: /pages/offer/management/219702
Date: 2019-09-30T08:30:18.736Z
Hash: 9afdb6037df5643d0cb2
Time: 512136ms
chunk {0} runtime.js, runtime.js.map (runtime) 1.45 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {1} main.js, main.js.map (main) 2.3 MB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {2} polyfills.js, polyfills.js.map (polyfills) 62 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {3} styles.js, styles.js.map (styles) 45.6 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {4} vendor.js, vendor.js.map (vendor) 1020 kB [initial] [rendered]
i ｢wdm｣: Compiled successfully.
```

Comment: Because you use AOT compilation, which builds your entire project. If I'm not mistaken, I think that [Ivy will resolve this issue](https://angular.io/guide/ivy)

Comment: I'm gonna try Ivy but with aot=false is building the entire project too. Let me check how Ivy works and i'll tell u. TY!

Comment: Yes, but JIT [compiles the code at runtime](https://angular.io/guide/aot-compiler)

Comment: [`JIT compilation is the default (as opposed to AOT compilation) when you run Angular's ng build and ng serve CLI commands, and is a good choice during development. JIT mode is strongly discouraged for production use because it results in large application payloads that hinder the bootstrap performance.`](https://angular.io/guide/glossary#J)

Comment: So if i dont use --aot the default is JIT?

Comment: see the time in my questions. 512136ms is more than 8 minutes! let me check without --optimization and without --aot

Comment: @Maryannah I've tryed with Ivy but then i've had some problems with import components. If i add Ivy i get an error because doesn't find pipe component..weird.
If anyone want, we can continue talking by telegram. https://t.me/l0c09 is my account

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Leave out `--optimization`. Then the build on change will take much less time. Try also without `--aot`. First build always takes some time. But then incremental build takes just a few seconds.

Comment: It should be a littl efaster. But just not that faster. --optimization is only needed for production builds.

Comment: The only problem is the website is slower than before. Why happend this?

Comment: Without `--aot` the templates are built in the browser.

Comment: I find that it's better to leave --aot an accept slower build time than accept building templates in browser and dealing with slow loading (37 seconds for my large SPA app).

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `ng s`. AOT and Optimization is needed only for production build.

```
ng s
```